# Replace a parameter value in url link using R

Tags: r, url

I am looking to find a way of inputting value of parameters in url link that I am using to access weather data using R programming.

Say in the following link, I want to change the

```
lat = 5
lon = 10
```

https://asdc-arcgis.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/power/v1beta/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150305&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=CLIMATOLOGY&outputList=JSON,ASCII&lat=-15.9200&lon=-47.6700

Manually I am able to access the information but in case I don't want someone to touch the code and input these values to a text file. The text file should have a link with url and substitutes these values directly to a url link.

If you know of any such approach. Please guide me to it!

Your help will be appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `glue` to do the substitution by wrapping the 'lat', 'lon' inside braces `{}`

```
glue::glue("https://asdc-arcgis.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/power/v1beta/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150305&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=CLIMATOLOGY&outputList=JSON,ASCII&lat={lat}&lon={lon}")
```

-output

```
#https://asdc-arcgis.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/power/v1beta/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150305&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=CLIMATOLOGY&outputList=JSON,ASCII&lat=5&lon=10
```

---

Or another option is `sprintf` from `base R`

```
sprintf("https://asdc-arcgis.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/power/v1beta/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150305&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=CLIMATOLOGY&outputList=JSON,ASCII&lat=%f&lon=%f", lat, lon)
```

-output

```
#[1] "https://asdc-arcgis.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/power/v1beta/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150305&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=CLIMATOLOGY&outputList=JSON,ASCII&lat=5.000000&lon=10.000000"
```

> 

Comment: I wanna keep lat, lon written but only change the values after equals to "="

Comment: @Jawairia  I changed in the `sprintf`

Comment: There is an issue. With lat, lon values zeros after point values did not matter but now when I am working on values like say startDate as 20150101 and endDate as 20151231, url is accepting as 20150101.0000 and 20151231.0000. Which is making issue in accessing data. Is  there any solution for this? I have tried `as.integer()` but that's not working either.

Comment: @Jawairia  It is because I used `%f` , instead it should be `%d` and `as.integer` for the lat and lon

Comment: @ akrun, understood now. Thanks a lot for your time!